# Node/ffmpeg Audio Duration: N/A when input is a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ffmpeg

I am currently trying to process an audio using node but taking a buffer as an input. This is what the code look's like so far.

```
let uLawArguments = [ // arguments for ulaw extention
    '-c',
    `ffmpeg -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mulaw -i -`
];

const ffMpeg = spawn('sh', uLawArguments);

ffMpeg.stdin.write(audioBuffer);
ffMpeg.stdin.end();
ffMpeg.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Ffmpeg takes `-i -` as an argument to accept the input throught stdin. After passing the buffer through, which is of type `Channel: 1, frequency: 8000`, I get the following output.

`Input #0, mulaw, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s`

I need to scrape the duration but before I can even format it, I need it to return the actual duration of the audio. I think the problem currently is that ffmpeg is outputting this to stderr before it can even process the buffer fully.

Comment: *the actual duration of the audio* - which audio? Of course, the length is N/A. Because it's unknown. You could probably calculate it from the buffer.

Comment: I took an audio, which is of type ulaw aka mulaw as defined. 

`const audioBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath)` I used that to get the buffer from a audio file I already have

Comment: Then you likely have to get duration from that file. Not from the one that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I can easily get it from a filePath. I already created a module that supports that. I need to add the feature to accept a buffer as well.

Comment: Btw, ffprobe is a good companion to ffmpeg that serves this purpose.

Comment: I tried it with ffprobe as well with no luck. It produces the same exact output as the one defined above with ffmpeg. After discussing it the error with some others, I believe it is because ffmpeg is outputting to stderr before it can process the buffer fully, which is why the Duration might be N/A. I am not proficient enough in either node or ffmpeg to force it to wait until the buffer is processed.

Comment: That's the idea. You want to get a duration of the file that doesn't exist yet. You need to get a duration of source file first - with ffprobe or else. I suppose it has same duration as output, doesn't it?